# How to cut path segments to fit the mask exactly [FIGMA]?

Tags: path, mask, figma

I've got a path under a circular mask. It has a colour fill. When I try to simply remove the parts of the path outside the mask, the path is no longer closed, and I lose the fill.  How to cut the path to the mask correctly? I aim to later divide it into smaller segments to modify them dynamically with CSS.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve here. Are you trying to cut the ellipse to make it vector, rather than have it simply masked, but still retain the red fill?

Comment: Hi! I am trying to get the path that is the exact shape of the coloured sections, without the need of a mask.

Comment: Then I would use a boolean Intersect operation. [see example here](https://imgur.com/xuanfwH). If this is what you want, I can add it as an answer.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need! Thank you! I will accept it as an answer when you add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do. Don't use a mask.

Instead, draw your ellipse and a square above it, (coloured red).

Select both and do a boolean Intersect operation

Do *Object > Flatten Selection* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. This will turn the Intersect object into a path.

An example

[image]